# How to Resize My Hard Drive in Ubuntu Using G Parted Partiton

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

Hi i am installed Ubuntu on my 500GB Hard disk. Now i want to install windows 10 on it. But for this i want to resize my 500GB Hard disk. But G Parted Partition does not allow me to make new partition for windows. What can i do please help me. I shall be very thankful to all of you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gparted will not let you resize a partition while Ubuntu is running on said partition.

To do this, you will need to use a live CD with Ubuntu (or any distro for that matter) and launch Gparted. From there you should be able to resize partitions as desired. If your going to edit the swap partition in any way you'll need to right click the partition and select `Swap off`.

P.S. Once you install Windoze 10, you'll want to boot from the live CD once again. Make sure the it's connected to the internet then run the following:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install boot-repair && sudo boot-repair`

Select `Recommended repair` and follow the instructions.

Windows likes to overwrite GRUB, but this will reinstall GRUB to fix that.

I hope this helps